Unable to create similar column headers using list comprehension as pandas does for a particular table
I'm trying to scrape headers of a table from a webpage using list comprehension. The problem I'm facing is that when I create the same headers using pandas, the appearance is vastly different. Just to inform you, the headers created by padas address all columns.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

link = 'https://www03.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/hmip-pimh/en/TableMapChart/TableMatchingCriteria?GeographyType=SurveyZone&GeographyId=011002&CategoryLevel1=Primary%20Rental%20Market&CategoryLevel2=Vacancy%20Rate%20%28%25%29&ColumnField=2&RowField=TIMESERIES'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

col_headers = [item.text.replace("\xa0","Unnamed: 0") for i in soup.select("table.CawdDataTable thead tr") for item in i.select("th, td")]
print(col_headers)

selector = soup.select_one("table.CawdDataTable")
df = pd.read_html(str(selector))[0]
print(list(df.columns))

Output: The first one is created by list comprehension, while the second one is created by pandas.
['Unnamed: 0', 'Bachelor', '1 Bedroom', '2 Bedroom', '3 Bedroom +', 'Total']
['Unnamed: 0', 'Bachelor', 'Bachelor.1', '1 Bedroom', '1 Bedroom.1', '2 Bedroom', '2 Bedroom.1', '3 Bedroom +', '3 Bedroom +.1', 'Total', 'Total.1']


Can I create similar column headers using list comprehension as pandas does?


It's because there are 11 items in the table and you create only 6 with your nested list comprehension. Ergo, pandas sees what you're actually removing. You'd have to massage the data to match your col_headers

You have to handle headers that span 2 columns. Look at the colspan attribute in the th , td tag. The table has 6 headers for 11 columns. The last 5 headers each span 2 columns.

IIUC you can do:
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www03.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/hmip-pimh/en/TableMapChart/TableMatchingCriteria?GeographyType=SurveyZone&GeographyId=011002&CategoryLevel1=Primary%20Rental%20Market&CategoryLevel2=Vacancy%20Rate%20%28%25%29&ColumnField=2&RowField=TIMESERIES"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

res = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.table

# remove colspan="2" from the <th>
for th in table.select("th[colspan]"):
    del th.attrs["colspan"]

# join every two <td>
for tr in table.select("tbody tr"):
    tds = tr.select("td")

    for i in range(0, len(tds), 2):
        td1, td2 = tds[i], tds[i + 1]
        td1.insert_before(
            BeautifulSoup(f"<td>{td1.text} {td2.text}</td>", "html.parser")
        )
        td1.extract()
        td2.extract()

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(table)))[0]
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0]).rename_axis(index=None)
print(df)

Prints:
             Bachelor 1 Bedroom 2 Bedroom 3 Bedroom +   Total
2010 October   13.3 a     9.6 a     6.2 a          **  11.0 a
2011 October   13.3 a    14.9 a     8.7 a          **  11.1 a
2012 October   13.3 a     8.0 a     6.4 a          **   7.9 a
2013 October    6.7 a     5.1 b     4.7 a          **   4.0 a
2014 October    0.0 a     5.8 a     4.2 a          **   3.8 a
2015 October       **     4.0 b     2.7 b          **   2.6 a
2016 October    0.0 a     1.8 b     0.8 a          **   1.4 a
2017 October    0.0 a     1.5 a     0.0 d          **   0.5 a
2018 October       **     3.4 d     0.6 a          **   1.6 b
2019 October    0.0 a     0.0 c     0.5 a          **   0.2 a
2020 October       **     1.4 d     0.7 a          **   0.8 a
2021 October       **        **     2.5 b          **   2.0 b
2022 October       **     5.0 c    10.8 d          **   7.3 a
2023 October       **        **        **          **      **

